# Google Datastore Client query.fetch() returns iterator for expected empty results

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a google datastore entity ('Users') which is currently empty and from the code i am trying to insert a new record. Before inserting a new record i am validating if the record exist but for some reason i am getting different output from query.fetch(). i am expecting query.fetch() result to be empty but below is the output of it. i am not sure on that

```
result <google.cloud.datastore.query.Iterator object at 0x7fee71d13ef0>
```

Complete code:

```
  def create(self):
    logger.log_text("create user request ")
    logger.log_text('email {}'.format(self.email))
    query = self.ds.query(kind=self.__tablename__)
    query.add_filter('email', '=', self.email)
    result = query.fetch()
    if result:
        logger.log_text('result {}'.format(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a query will always return an iterator.   See this page on the [google.cloud.datastore.query.Iterator](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/queries.html).  The iterator allows you to step through the results.  This includes a query response where there are no results.  It looks like the property called `num_results` may be of value to us as it seems to return the count of results that are available to be iterated over.  If `num_results` is 0, then the query returned no items.